# How to get specific items in plist to show in tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a plist in this format:

[image]

I currently show all the content of plist.My main question is this

How can I show only based on the category? I will have 3 categories and I want to make the user able to see just that category's item in selection. Look at my first item, the category name is 'main'. If user select main I need to show only main categories items.

How can I accomplish this?

```
'

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if( [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"recipeName"];
   // NSInteger rating;
    //NSString *reason;

   // rating = [[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"rating"];

    return cell;


    // Configure the cell...



'
```

content

```
    synthesize tableView,content=_content;

-(NSArray*) content {

    if(!_content){


        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipes" ofType:@"plist" ];
        _content  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    }
    return _content;
}
```

segue part

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        // Get destination view
        detailViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];

        destViewController.recipeName =[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"recipeName"];
        destViewController.recipeDetail =[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"recipeDetail"];
        destViewController.recipeIngredients =[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"recipeIngredients"];
```

these are the main parts

Comment: What's your code? What did you achieve so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new property to keep the filtered list:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredContent;
```

Then change the tableView and segue methods so that if there is a filter active, they would access the self.filteredContent array instead of self.content.

Finally, when changing the filter to main:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in self.content)
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"category"] isEqualToString:@"main"])
        [array addObject:dictionary];
self.filteredContent = array;           //filtered list

[self.tableView reloadData];    //update the table view
```

Hope it works for what you need...